# Simplest handling of NaN in bound form input in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

How can I cause numbers with no value to show up blank instead of NaN on forms?

Let's say I have a User class with an optional weight (kgs) value, of type Number. If I edit a User in Flex I get the user object from the server and bind weightInput.text to user.weight. If weight is null on the server it will be translated to NaN in Flex, and then the value of weight in the edit form showes up as NaN. That is really inconvenient, as I would like it to just be blank if it has no value.

Is there a recommended/simple way to handle this? I would have thought that it is a really common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `NumberFormatter`:

```
<fx:Declarations>   
    <mx:NumberFormatter id="numeric" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Label text="number is {numeric.format(myNumber)}" />
```

Or, if you don't want to use a formatter, you can use `isNaN()`:

```
<s:Label text="number is {isNaN(myNumber) ? '' : myNumber}" />
```

Good lucks :)

Comment: Thanks, I went for the formatter. I find Flex has the ability to do a lot of things well, but it does sometimes suffer from requiring a lot of typing when newer frameworks just do sensible things by default.

Comment: I suppose it depends.  In some ways, Flex is extremely succinct. In other ways, it is wordy.  It all depends on which facet of the framework you are looking at.  What newer frameworks are you referring to?  Just curious.

Comment: RAD stuff like Rails and Grails

Comment: I fairness, RIA frameworks and Web frameworks aim to solve different problems.  I don't find the above to be terribly wordy.  I have seen a lot worse, at least :)